# ISO 8601 with milliseconds and Retrofit

Tags: java, android, date, gson, iso8601

I cannot set properly the date format when using retrofit and trying to read a date like this:

```
2015-08-29T11:22:09.815479Z
```

An the [GSON](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gson) converter I'm setting is like this:

```
GsonConverter gsonConverter = new GsonConverter(
     new GsonBuilder()
            .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSz")
            .create()
);
```

Any clues on what's the problem?

Comment: Use the classes in the [java.time framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) built into Java 8 and later. They have a resolution of nanoseconds for up to nine digits of a fractional second.

Answer (score 11):

Java [Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) has millisecond precision so I've been creating the `Gson` object like so:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
        .create();
```

Of course, in a case like this, the microseconds are being truncated whether you put `SSS` or `SSSSSS`. It is also assumed that the last character of the converted string is always a `Z`.

To explain why your pattern didn't work, you used `z` (lowercase z) which according to the documentation represents a [General Timezone](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#timezone) (e.g., `Pacific Standard Time; PST; GMT-08:00`). Additionally, if you were to use `Z` (uppercase Z), it would also not work since it represents an [RFC 822 time zone](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#rfc822timezone) (e.g., `-0800`).

In another scenario where instead of the `Z` you have a time zone offset (e.g., `-08`, `-0800`, or `-08:00`), you can use `X`, `XX`, or `XXX` to represent an [ISO 8610 time zone](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#iso8601timezone). But that requires Java 7 or 8 (I don't think Android is compatible with Java 8 at the moment).

---

Another method would be to write your own `Gson` [Serializer and Deserializer](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Custom-Serialization-and-Deserialization); although I haven't tried.

It's also worth looking at [java.sql.Timestamp](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) class which is also supported by `Gson` and has more fine grained precision (nanoseconds) but it's also an option I haven't explored.

Comment: Much of the java.time functionality built into Java 8 and later is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (see [*How to use…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706)).

Comment: Is this really ISO 8601 compatible? I have never seen millis in the official spec. This looks like an extension of the standard format.

Comment: @ChristopheRoussy While I've not read the ISO 8601 specification directly as it is copyrighted and expensive, according to [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601): *There is no limit on the number of decimal places for the decimal fraction. However, the number of decimal places needs to be agreed to by the communicating parties.* In *java.time*, the various classes such as `Instant` resolve to nanoseconds (nine digits of decimal fraction).

Comment: I presume your formatting pattern here is ignoring the `Z` by enclosing in single-quote marks. This means you are **ignoring crucial information**: the offset-from-UTC or time zone. Likely to have bad effects, though I do not know exactly what the effects are in `GsonBuilder`.

Answer (score 4):

Java 8 [Instant](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class can be used to easily parse [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) timestamps without explicitly setting a format string, for example:

```
String input = "2018-11-07T00:25:00.073876Z";
Instant instant = Instant.parse(input);
```